# is there a "force quit" option for pygame programs?

Tags: pygame, infinite-loop

I have defined a "game loop"
function, (the code below)
but for some reason it doesn't
exit upon trying close the window
(the "quit event")
despite there being code written to break the loop if
you do that.
I have tried handling the event in question
by using a variable to dictate when the loop
should run, as well as handling using a break statement
to close the loop. neither have worked.

```py
##game loop
def main():
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    run = True
    while run:
        clock.tick(FPS)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == quit:
                run = False
        draw_all()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you compare the event type to the predefined `quit` function of python.  This is obviously never evaluted to `True`.

Do instead `if event.type == pygame.QUIT:`.